# Electron detect global scroll event mac

Tags: javascript, macos, events, scroll, electron

How can I detect a global scroll event on Electron? So far I've only found `BrowserWindow.on('scroll-touch-begin')`, which only works if the cursor is scrolling within the browser window. How can I detect EVERY scroll event?

I know this can be done natively with Swift, but no idea if that's possible on Electron. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook) package from npm. it has all global event key and mouse listeners.